# change a class component into a functional component to fix '_id' is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change a class component into a functional component so that I can delete questions that are rendered onto the screen. My main focus is mainly  deletedQuestion().

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Axios from "axios"
import { deleteQuestion } from './InputQuestionsFunctions'


export default function () {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        getQuestions()
    }, [])

    async function getQuestions() {
        try {

            const res = await Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/QuestionsRoute/me", {
                headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("usertoken")}` }
            })
            // if(res.status)
            setQuestions(res.data)
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log("error while getting questions", e)
        }
    }

    const deletedQuestion = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault() 
        const removedQuestion = {
            id:_id
        }

        deleteQuestion(removedQuestion)
        .then(res => {this.props.history.push('/profile')
        })
    }


    const renderQuestions = () => {
        return questions.map(eachQuestion => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <button onClick={(e) => deletedQuestion(e)}
                        className="mdi mdi-delete mdi-24px lifeline-icon" />

                    <p> {eachQuestion.question}</p>

                    <p style={{ color: "blue" }}> {eachQuestion.answer}</p>

                </div >
            )
        })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {renderQuestions()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

right now the _id is undefined but ideally `onClick={(e) => deletedQuestion(e)}` would use the id to delete the specific question. Below is the imported () for reference!

```
export const deleteQuestion = removedQuestion => {
    const body = {
        id:removedQuestion._id
    }
    const options = {
        headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("usertoken")}` }
    };
    return axios

        .delete(
            process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER + '/QuestionsRoute/me/_id',
            body,
            options
        ).then(res => {
            console.log('Deleted')
        })
}
```

I'm new I would greatly appreciate the edited code but any help is  appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the question in the `.map` so pass it through when you call `deletedQuestion`:

```js
    const deletedQuestion = (e, question) => {
        e.preventDefault() 
        const removedQuestion = {
            id: question._id
        }
        deleteQuestion(removedQuestion)
          .then(res => {this.props.history.push('/profile')
        })
    }

...

<button onClick={(e) => { deletedQuestion(e, eachQuestion); }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `deletedQuestion` block, there is no `_id` variable, that's why it is undefined.
- You need to pass `eachQuestion._id` to `deletedQuestion`

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Axios from "axios"
import { deleteQuestion } from './InputQuestionsFunctions'


export default function () {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        getQuestions()
    }, [])

    async function getQuestions() {
        try {

            const res = await Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/QuestionsRoute/me", {
                headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("usertoken")}` }
            })
            // if(res.status)
            setQuestions(res.data)
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log("error while getting questions", e)
        }
    }

// Now you have _id
    const deletedQuestion = (e, _id) => {
        e.preventDefault() 
        const removedQuestion = {
            id:_id
        }

        deleteQuestion(removedQuestion)
        .then(res => {this.props.history.push('/profile')
        })
    }


    const renderQuestions = () => {
        return questions.map(eachQuestion => {
            return (
                <div>
                {/* pass eachQuestion._id into  deletedQuestion*/}
                    <button onClick={(e) => deletedQuestion(e, eachQuestion._id)} 
                        className="mdi mdi-delete mdi-24px lifeline-icon" />

                    <p> {eachQuestion.question}</p>

                    <p style={{ color: "blue" }}> {eachQuestion.answer}</p>

                </div >
            )
        })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {renderQuestions()}
        </div>
    )
}
```